# Route Model Binding multiple parameters for tenant prefix Route::resource()

Tags: php, laravel, api, multi-tenant

I'm developing an API using Laravel's [Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers) features and using [Orchestral Multi-tenant Database Schema Manager](http://orchestraplatform.com/docs/latest/components/tenanti#single-db-setup) as a **Single Database**.

In my control methods I am using the [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-model-binding) to injecting a model ID to a route or controller action, often query to retrieve the model that corresponds to that ID.

Some relevant **routes** from my API:

```
| POST      | api/v1/{tenant}/fornecedores                     | store  | App\Http\Controllers\Api\Fornecedor\FornecedorController@store  | api,tenant,jwt.auth |
| GET|HEAD  | api/v1/{tenant}/fornecedores                     | index  | App\Http\Controllers\Api\Fornecedor\FornecedorController@index  | api,tenant,jwt.auth |
| GET|HEAD  | api/v1/{tenant}/fornecedores/count               |        | App\Http\Controllers\Api\Fornecedor\FornecedorController@count  | api,tenant,jwt.auth |
| PUT|PATCH | api/v1/{tenant}/fornecedores/{fornecedor}        | update | App\Http\Controllers\Api\Fornecedor\FornecedorController@update | api,tenant,jwt.auth |
| GET|HEAD  | api/v1/{tenant}/fornecedores/{fornecedor}        | show   | App\Http\Controllers\Api\Fornecedor\FornecedorController@show   | api,tenant,jwt.auth |
| GET|HEAD  | api/v1/{tenant}/fornecedores/{fornecedor}/audits |        | App\Http\Controllers\Api\Fornecedor\FornecedorController@audits | api,tenant,jwt.auth |
...
```

An example of my **API route file**:

```
// API V1
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1/{tenant}', 'middleware' => 'tenant'], function () {

    // Fornecedores
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'fornecedores'], function () {
        Route::get('count', 'Api\Fornecedor\FornecedorController@count');
        Route::get('{fornecedor}/audits', 'Api\Fornecedor\FornecedorController@audits');

        Route::resource('/', 'Api\Fornecedor\FornecedorController', [
            'parameters' => ['' => 'fornecedor'],
            'except' => ['create', 'edit', 'destroy']
        ]);
    });
});
```

These are some methods of my **FornecedorController.php**:

```
public function index()
{
    return $this->fornecedorService->getFornecedoresPaginate();
}

// This is line 48 (throw below):
public function show(Fornecedor $fornecedor)
{
    return $fornecedor;
}
```

However when trying to access the URL that uses the Route Model Binding I get the following error:

**URL:** /api/v1/1/fornecedores/1

```
FatalThrowableError in FornecedorController.php line 48:
Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Api\Fornecedor\FornecedorController::show() must be an instance of App\Models\Fornecedor, string given
```

And this is the all trace:

```
in FornecedorController.php line 48
at FornecedorController->show('1', object(Fornecedor))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(FornecedorController), 'show'), array('tenant' => '1', 'fornecedor' => object(Fornecedor))) in  Controller.php line 55
at Controller->callAction('show', array('tenant' => '1', 'fornecedor' => object(Fornecedor))) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 44
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(FornecedorController), 'show') in Route.php line 203
at Route->runController() in Route.php line 160
at Route->run() in Router.php line 559
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 30
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in GetUserFromToken.php line 46
at GetUserFromToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in
...
```

I could verify that there is apparently a confusion when retrieving the parameters. When inspecting route parameters, this is the result:

```
public function show($fornecedor)
{
    dd(\Route::current()->parameters());
}
```

URL: /api/v1/1/fornecedores/18

Result:

```
array:2 [
  "tenant" => "1"
  "fornecedor" => "18"
]
```

And when trying to retrieve the provider's route:

```
public function show($fornecedor)
{
    dd($fornecedor);
}
```

URL: /api/v1/1/fornecedores/18

Result:

```
"1"
```

Even using bind the parameter I get is not correct. And the other routes that do not use a second parameter are ok.

Can someone tell me a better approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First guess is that you are trying to bind your `fornecedor` parameter implicitly and Laravel cannot resolve or identify it.

You can declare your parameter-model relationship somewhere below in your routes file (`routes/web.php` or `routes.php`)

```
Route::model('fornecedor', \App\Models\ Fornecedor::class);
```

Also your `show` method does not cater for the `tenent` parameter. The method should look like this:

```
public function show($tenant, Fornecedor $fornecedor){
    return $fornecedor;
}
```

or

```
public function show(Tenant $tenant, Fornecedor $fornecedor){
    return $fornecedor;
}
```